# Change resolution (chooseable)

Tags: screen-resolution

I want to change the resolution of my game in the menu. Now I've made a nice method where it looks up if the resolution is available for this PC and changes then it does:

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = iWidth;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = iHeight;
ScreenManager.sScreenSize.X = iWidth;
ScreenManager.sScreenSize.Y = iHeight;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

`sScreenSize` is just a rectangle for the buttons to position and such things.

When I call this function at start then everything is right, but if I call it in the menu, the resolution changes, but nothing that gets drawn changes. So I see only some percent of the screen. How do I fix it? I can only find online how to initialize the resolution.

Comment: What language/framework are you talking about?

Comment: Oh sh*t, it looks like i accidentaly deleted that part. I'm talking about C# in Monogame.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the screen before I changed the resolution and then add the screen then again.